# How to handle special characters while unmarshalling xml in JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

my test xml content

```
    <p id="033" num="03">geopotent change&#x2 high.</p>
```

And I run Jaxb Unmarshalling, but I'm getting exception

```
    09:58:43.748 ERROR [main][net.ServiceImpl] Parsing Error: 
    javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException- with linked exception:    
    [javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:
    [161,306]Message: String "&#]
```

my Jaxb unmarshal source is

```
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(CnDocument.class);
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    document = (CnDocument) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlFile);
```

How can I escape those characters? (&#x2)

Answer (score 0):

You get a JAXB parse error because your XML content is not well-formed.
It should be `&#x2;` (with semicolon), not `&#x2`.

Answer (score 0):

`<p id="033" num="03">geopotent change&#x2 high.</p>` is not valid XML. Either "escape" the ampersand character using `&amp;` or make the character reference complete by adding a semicolon: `&#x2;`.

Answer (score -1):

This is one way you can do:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.Writer;

import com.sun.xml.bind.marshaller.CharacterEscapeHandler;

public class XmlCharacterHandler implements CharacterEscapeHandler {

    public void escape(char[] buf, int start, int len, boolean isAttValue,
            Writer out) throws IOException {
        StringWriter buffer = new StringWriter();

        for (int i = start; i < start + len; i++) {
            buffer.write(buf[i]);
        }

        String st = buffer.toString();

        if (!st.contains("CDATA")) {
            st = buffer.toString().replace("&", "&amp;").replace("<", "&lt;")
                .replace(">", "&gt;").replace("'", "&apos;")
                .replace("\"", "&quot;");

        }
        out.write(st);
        System.out.println(st);
    }

}
```

While marshaling :

```
marshaller.setProperty(CharacterEscapeHandler.class.getName(),
                new XmlCharacterHandler());
```

Comment: unmarshaller is not support CharacterEscapeHandler.

Comment: @min: You can handle it is logic as mentioned in my first code snapshot.